# Onfocus of textbox clear other textbox in the same row in razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

i am working on mvc application , in my table list i have two textbox in same row, i want a validation that user can enter data in only one textbox. both the textboxex are of prices so user can only enter price in one textbox. if entering price in textbox should write 0 in another textbox in the same row.i have done something like this :

```
<td id="tdprice">
    <input type="text" id="txtprice" class="inputprice" onfocus="changeValues('@string.Format(" tr{0} ", @item.Id)','inputmarkup')" value="@string.Format(" {0:0.00} ", item.ManualPrice)" style="width:50px" />
</td>
<td id="tdmarkup">
    <input type="text" id="txtmarkup" class="inputmarkup" onfocus="changeValues('@string.Format(" tr{0} ", @item.Id)','inputprice')" value="@string.Format(" {0:0.00} ", item.MarkUp)" style="width:50px" />
</td>
```

My java script Function :

```
function changeValues(tr, css) {
    alert(tr);
    alert(css);
    var tr1 = "'#" + tr + "'";
    var css1 = "'." + css + "'";
    $(this).closest(tr1).find(css1).val('');
}
```

in this function i am getting two values , first the table row and textbox which i want to set as 0.how do i do that ? also this java script fired in the first row only why so ?? immediate help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7NLa8/1

```
$('table tr td input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]').not(this).val('');
});
```